# How much Bitcoin was lost in the Jul. 2011 MyBitcoin site shutdown incident?

Tags: theft, hacking

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MyBitcoin

How much money was lost when it shut down? (You can also edit the wiki page and add this info). Best estimates of course.

Comment: Did they run off with the money but claimed they were "hacked"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this speculative thread at bitcointalk.org forums](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=33389.0), a minimum of 27,000 BTC (worth $370,000 USD at that time), with a possible maximum of 75,000 BTC, estimated.

Here's a screen cap of the first post in the thread, in case the forum later disappears:

[image: 1st post in bitcointalk.org forum thread on 2011 MyBitcoin losses]